# How to count average value for each user?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two tables: `users, comments`.

Each user has some comments.

I do request like as:

```
$users = User:with('comments')->get();
```

How can I count the average value in field `comments.rate` `where users.id = comments.user_id`

In result I should get collection with all rows wityh user information and field `avg_rate`

I tried to use `->avg()`, but it returns only one row, not for each

I have own solution, but I have desire to move this code in model:

```
{{$users->reviewsAverage()->first()->avg("rate")}}
```

**Model:**

```
public function reviewsAverage()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Review', 'user_id', 'id'); //->first()->avg('rate');
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: how to get average on nested hasMany relationships (hasManyThrough)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698690/laravel-how-to-get-average-on-nested-hasmany-relationships-hasmanythrough)

Answer (score 0):

Have two functions one for the relationship and he other for the average function

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Comment', 'id');
}

public function averageRating()
{
    return $this->comments()->selectRaw('avg(rate) as average_rate, comment_id')
                            ->groupBy('comment_id');
}
```

Then go ahead and query like this

```
foreach($users as $user){
    $rate = $user->averageRate();
}
```